# C# Selenium Chrome error: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.ScreenshotImageFormat'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with selenium in C#. 
Below is my code but I have still the same error:
**cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.ScreenshotImageFormat'**

How can I fix it? Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Drawing;
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("xx://xx.xx.xx");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("xx")).SendKeys("xxx");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("xx")).SendKeys("xxx");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("xx")).Click();

            Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
            ss.SaveAsFile(@"C:\\test.Png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("xxx");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It says right at the top of the doc given by seleniumhq.  `[ObsoleteAttribute("System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat is not supported in .NET Core, and depending on it is being removed from WebDriver. Please convert to ScreenshotImageFormat.")]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png` as the 2nd param of your SaveAsFile, you need to use `OpenQA.Selenium.ScreenshotImageFormat.[something here]`

That enum probably has it's own PNG format.

Comment: It works ! Thanks 

Resolution

 ss.SaveAsFile(@"C:\\test.Png,OpenQA.Selenium.ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);

Comment: You might want to change your file extension, may have incompatibility down the road maybe as your extension says png, but the file format is actually a jpeg.  *shrugs*

Answer (score 4):

The error was persistent, saying:

> System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat is not supported. Please change format.

Then I changed code from:

```
ScreenShot.SaveAsFile(FileName.ToString(), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

To:

```
ScreenShot.SaveAsFile(FileName.ToString(), ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
ss.SaveAsFile(@"C:\\test.Png", 
  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Change to:

```
ss.SaveAsFile(@"C:\\test.Png", 
  System.Drawing.Imaging.ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
```

Also use or import:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

Comment: A short answer is welcome, however it won't provide much value to the latter users who are trying to understand what's going on behind the problem. Please spare some time to explain what's the real issue to cause the problem and how to solve. Thank you ~